# SurfaceView: ClassCastException, unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

Trying to get an Android 2.2 application to start up with a SurfaceView as the base view with a button placed atop it located near the bottom of the screen.  So far, no luck.  It crashes every time it attempts to launch.  I've checked to make sure that the activity is registered in the manifest.

Here's my java code:

```
public class Dragable extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

and here's my `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/surface_home"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:text="@string/add_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</SurfaceView>
```

and my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Dragable"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

and here's my error:

`11-29 11:58:52.620: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(512): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Dragable}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.SurfaceView`

Can't seem to find anything related doing searches on SO.  My appologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: Is that all you have in your activity? If no, could you paste the complete activity code, please?

Comment: @Cristian that's it.  There's nothing more in there to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I see the problem. [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) is not a container, I mean it does not extends `ViewGroup`, so you can't put a `Button` inside a `SurfaceView`. What you can do is wrapping the `SurfaceView` and the `Button` within a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks much.  This was driving me up a wall.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using any container to place components. Use this and make changes

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<SurfaceView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/surface_home"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_new"
    android:text="@string/add_new"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
/>
 </SurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to use any container. For instance, you can use a `TextView` as the root element of an XML layout (and nothing else, of course), and it will work just fine. By the way, the code you pasted will also fail.